# SQL - Select Rows that are the same except for one row

Tags: sql

I'm quite the SQL n00b and I can't seem to figure this out so hoping for some help (its pretty simple!).

I have a table of data being generated from data being scraped off a website. The data only changes every so often with new information arriving and old information disappearing the data scrape gets run every minute.

Columns: `TimeStamp, User, RowA, RowB, RowC`

The first column is a `timestamp` value and the rest of the rows are often then the same if there is no new content that is generated on the webpage over that minute.

What I want to do is figure out the time between when new data arrives on the page and when it disappears.

To do this I figure I can do a select statement that checks for rows where A B C are all the same except for the timestamp value and then compares the time difference between the first result and the last result.

Example:

```
10:00AM, James, Apples, Oranges, Pears
10:01AM, James, Apples, Oranges, Pears
10:02AM, James, Apples, Oranges, Pears 
10:03AM, James, Apples, Watermelon
```

What I want to know is that the row `James, Apples, Oranges, Pears` was there from between 10:00AM and 10:03AM and be able to calculate that it was there for 3 minutes.

Any help as always is greatly appreciated.

**UPDATE**:
To further clarify this, this won't be a query where the values are known - it will need to look at the values received from the query and compare them to see if they are the same (except the timestamp) - thanks for the volume of responses guys I really appreciate it

Comment: You have columns named RowA, RowB, RowC?

Comment: oddly enough, yes - might have to update that due to the ambiguity

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the variety of sql, you'll probably want to use a a date function to subtract the timestamps. If you get rid of the where clasue you'll see grouping.

```
Select
  RowA, -- Calling columns "Row" isn't confusing at all
  RowB,
  RowC,
  Min(timestamp),
  Max(timestamp),
  Max(timestamp) - Min(timestamp)
From
  Scrape
Where
  RowA = 'James' And
  RowB = 'Apples' And 
  RowC = 'Oranges'
Group By
  RowA,
  RowB,
  RowC
```

Comment: Hi Laurence, ill check this out a bit later when I can test this and up vote if applicable!

Comment: That does assume that once the data changes, it ***never*** returns back to the same values at a later date.

Comment: Absolutely, if that's not the case then Gordon's approach is the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

You can calculate the difference from max and min time:

```
select `user`, rowa, rowb, rowc,
       min(`timestamp`), max(`timestamp`),
       timediff(min(`timestamp`), max(`timestamp`))
from mytable
group by `user`, rowa, rowb, rowc;
```

Comment: That does assume that once the data changes, it ***never*** returns back to the same values at a later date.

Answer (score 0):

Presumably, your data values can be repeated.  In your example, James, Apples, Oranges, Pears could reappear at 11:00 a.m., and that would be a new sequence.

The idea behind the query is to find when each group ends.  This looks forward to the next record where the data values are different and the time stamp is larger.  In fact, the minimum such time stamp identifies the group.  You could actually do something similar looking backwards, but I prefer looking forward.

The way to do this in standard SQL is using a correlated subquery (or non-equijoin), as follows:

```
select user, RowA, RowB, RowC, min(TimeStamp) as StartTimeStamp,
       EndTimeStamp
from (select User, RowA, RowB, RowC, TimeStamp,
             (select Min(timeStamp)
              from t t2
              where t2.TimeStamp > t1.TimeStamp and
                    (t2.user <> t.user or
                     t2.RowA <> t.rowA or
                     t2.RowB <> t.RowB or
                     t2.RowC <> t.RowC
                    )
             ) as EndTimeStampe
      from t
     ) t
group by user, RowA, RowB, RowC, EndTimeStamp
```

Note that this assumes that the values are not NULL, because NULLs would automatically fail the comparison even when "equal".  You can fix this on of two ways:

```
(coalesce(t2.user, '<null>') <> coalesce(t.user, '<null'>) or . . .
```

or

```
(t2.user <> t.user and ((t2.user is not null and t.user is null) or (t2.user is null and t.user is not null))
```

Some dialects of SQL (such as SQL Server 2012 and Oracle) offer more extensive window functions that can also help solve this problem.

Also, if you have very large tables, this is rather inefficient.  It helps if you have an index on (TimeStamp, user, RowA, RowB, RowC).

Comment: This is looking a bit more what I need but I think the values in the where claus would want to be equal instead of notequal - again I'll check this out when I have the opportunity tonight and up vote what best fits ;) thanks heaps.

Comment: Errr, no, the not equal is correct.  It's looking for the First row After this one where the values are different - This gives the end time for the group.  (Or NULL if this is the last group.)

Comment: @Dems . . . The subquery finds the EndTimeStamp for each group.  The end time stamp is the identifier for each group (along with the other columns).   and the outer query groups by that, to bring together the appropriate rows.

Comment: @GordonLinoff - I agree, I tried to explain that in response to Lance, not a response to your anwer :)